# gnu/libtool (libltdl) installed but not found by configure script

Tags: installation, makefile, gnu, guile, libltdl

I am trying to install [guile](https://github.com/cky/guile) locally on a system. It requires gnu/libtool. While installing all its dependencies, the "`make check`" command showed errors while installing gnu/libtool. But if I omitted the command and simply ran "`make`" followed by "`make install`", then it was able to install successfully. I was able to install the rest of the dependencies without any problem. However, when I run the following command, then I am getting the below mentioned error:

Command:

```
../configure --with-libltdl-prefix=$PREFIX/libtool --with-libgmp-prefix=$PREFIX/gmp --with-libunistring-prefix=$PREFIX/libunistring --with-libiconv-prefix=$PREFIX/libiconv --with-libreadline-prefix=$PREFIX/libreadline --with-libintl-prefix=$PREFIX/gettext --prefix=$PREFIX/guile
```

Error:

```
configure: error: GNU libltdl (Libtool) not found, see README.
```

the `$PREFIX` is defined and I have installed the `libltdl` library in the `libtool` folder. When I look through the `include` and `lib` sub directories of the `libtool` folder, I can find the `libltdl` folders and .so files.

So, I am unsure as to why the configure script is not able to find the locally installed version of `libtool`. I will be highly grateful if someone can point out the problem in the command and how to remedy this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95207/discussion-between-python-user-and-chris-jester-young).

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I have the same problem now.

Comment: So, how is this issue solved? I'm having a similar issue after upgrading my ubuntu to 18.04. guile complained that it can't find libunistring.so then I tried to compile and install where configure threw an error about not finding libltdl.so. I tried setting LDFLAGS and libltdl-with-prefix flags one at a time but didn't solve it.

Comment: @Levi This was looong time ago. I believe I gave up on this and I had to retake a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to compile bind9 using distcc under Rasbian. I had previously installed the package *libtool* but I was also missing the package *libtool-bin*.
That solved my issue.
Try

```
apt list libtool* --installed
```

and see if both show up.